# How to turn off 'Back to the future' on the SO website?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, design, time-travel-mode

A couple minutes ago, the website turned into a old version of SO (Back to the future).

[image]

Even if I switch to the normal design (via button 'Time travel!'), the next post of SO will still have the '90s design.

How can I turn it off permanently?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I searched only for "back to the future" - did not thought of "time travel". Thanks, it is a duplicate!